# Financial Bonds 500 $1,000 bonds with stated rate of 5% issued at par. 10 year term and pay interest semi-annually.

Tags: analysis, finance

Every time I try and calculate this problem something comes up wrong. Either from working it out by hand or using my BA II plus, I cannot get the answer shown below. Am I wrong or is this book answer off?

500 bonds at $1,000 with a stated rate of 5%.

The present value $500000,

payable in 20 six-month periods at a market rate of 5% is **$305,135.47**. But I cannot come up with that number, using a BA II plus caculator or doing the calculations by hand.

The present value of 12,500 of intrest (500000 x 5% interest / 2 payments per year) paid for 20 six-months periods at a market rate of 5% is 194864.53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Par value is the dollar amount that will be paid to the bondholder at maturity of the bond, i.e., in ten years.  Interest does not actually accrue on the bond; rather, the prospective bondholder calculates what they should pay now for the bond, given the effective interest rate that they desire, which is 5% in this case.

So $500,000 is the future value (FV) of the bonds.  Then, we can calculate the present value (PV) by the following:

$$
\mathrm{FV}=$500,000=\mathrm{PV}(1.025)^{20}
$$

Solving for PV gives

$$
\mathrm{PV}=\frac{$500,000}{(1.025)^{20}}=$305,135.47
$$

Let me know if this makes sense or not.

Comment: Yeah thats what I would get. I added the value of the intrest payments that it shows too.

The point of this slide is showing that "when a bond sells at par, bond holders earn the stated rate of intrest" "this is true because the present value of the face amount and the present value of the intrest payments are equal to the face value "

Comment: Either the slides are wrong or I am missing a simple concept.

Comment: Oh okay. Thats it I was using 1.05 instead of 1.025. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielLoisi Glad I could help!